# Antlr4 tree parser I have problems with numbers like (9-34)*9

Tags: regex, antlr4

I have created a tree with antlr4.The tree performs the calculation steps, for +, -., * and /. The tree works perfectly for positive numbers, my problem is, for negative numbers, like when I enter (9-40)*10 or so, it doesn't work anymore.

My code is:

```
calculator:
    (d)*| ;
    
c:
    c '*' c | c '/' c | c '+' c | c '-' c | '(' c ')' | b | a ;
d:
     a '=' c ;

b :   '-'?[0-9]+;         
a: [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*;

WS  :   [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(please be careful to verify your source before your post.  The grammar, as posted, is not valid ANTLR.  Probably because you changed rule names to `a`, `b`, etc. and forgot to keep Lexer rules uppercase.)

If I assume to be the case, here's a modified grammar to address your problem.

```
grammar calc
    ;

calculator: (d)*;

c
    : c '*' c
    | c '/' c
    | c '+' c
    | c '-' c
    | '(' c ')'
    | '-'? NBR // <-- The fix
    | ID
    ;
d: ID '=' c;

NBR: [0-9]+; // <-- removed the '-'?
ID:  [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*;

WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

The source of the problem is, that by putting the `-` in the Lexer rule, ANTLR will match the "-40" as a NBR token, since it's a longer string of characters than "40".  The solution is to handle the negation as an alternative in you parser rule for c (aka expression)

It's always a good idea to use the ANTLR tool (aka `grun`) the the `-tokens` option to get a dump of your token stream to ensure that your Lexer rules are giving the parser the token stream that it needs.

Comment: Hello now we have the problem that we cannot distinguish - as a sign and as an operator. Do you have a tip for this?

Comment: do you have a specific example?  just tried "2-5" and "2- -5" and both were handled correctly.

Comment: yes for example (-2-5)*10. Antlr4 has now problems with the - from the 2

Comment: I just ran that string through and got this parse tree "(c (c ( (c (c - 2) - (c 5)) )) * (c 10))".  That seems correct.

Comment: Yes and this is the problem. You have: (c (c ( (c (c - 2) - (c 5)) )) * (c 10)) correct would be (c (c ( (c (c -2) - (c 5)) )) * (c 10)), not space between the - and the 2, because - is not a operator, its belongs to the 2

Comment: That is correct.  It matching the alternative that finds the - and the NBR.  It’ll be up to you to negate the number.  It is an operator (of sorts)